# How to manage stateful reducers in Redux?

Tags: redux

I'm starting to read up on Redux and I like what I see so far. There is one area of concern that I have and it's async actions. I've seen how sagas, thunk, and others help in this area but I feel like I'm missing something.

I'm a fan of using FSMs to handle application logic and prevent things from getting out of sync, so coming to redux and not seeing something like this is a bit jarring to me.

I have an example in my mind that I keep coming back to that I want redux (or some plugin) to solve:

I have a login form. When the user presses login, an async call is made to a server. This is fine. But if the user presses login again, then another call is made to the server and the application state is now out of sync. I could add a state property that defines `loggingIn`, but this only works in this example.

Lets say I have a much bigger dependency. Lets say when a user logs in, an action is done to preload some data. And that data contains a preflight of more data to load. This now introduces a lot of if/else conditional logic and adds more information to the state. In a FSM, I would define multiple concurrent states for theses. Such as `user:loggedIn`, `manifest:fetched`, `pageData:fetched`. And each state would be a child of each other: `user:loggedIn -> manifest:fetched -> pageData:fetched`. So if a request was made to login, or refetch data, an error would be thrown because it's not a valid handler for the current state. How does one accomplish such complexity in Redux? Is it even possible?

Another example. Stemming off the Reddit API example. Lets say a user goes to a reddit post. I don't want the user to be able to submit a comment on the post before it's even loaded. I know this could be handled on the UI side with conditionals and such, but that seems really archaic.

I really appreciate any guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: You should disable your `login` button until the action is completed

Comment: @AbhinavSingi That's a fine solution, but I don't want to rely on the frontend preventing the backend from doing something.

Comment: You should really consider [`redux-saga`](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga).

Comment: middleware like the one in the [redux real world example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/64a8c66b454163660f9d49bcce92a3230cdbcb2a/examples/real-world/middleware/api.js) generalize the pattern of defining a loading state. This is a higher order function returning a reducer which you can combine with your other reducers.